# React: how to force state changes to take place after setState

Tags: javascript, html, css, design-patterns, reactjs

How to force the state update to take place in React after calling setState?

As far as I know, state is effectively updated when render is called next time. Also, `forceUpdate()` should re-render the component and update the state changes immediately, right? However this doesn't seem to be the case. Here's an example.

```
handleSomeEvent(data) {
    this.setState({
        data: data
    })
    this.forceUpdate()

    // At this point state should be updated but it isn't
    this.props.consumeData(this.state.data) // consumeData will receive old data
}
```

How do I ensure state is actually updated before calling consumeData?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`setState()` is asynchronous, so you can do it in the callback:

```
handleSomeEvent(data) {
  this.setState({
    data: data
  }, () => this.props.consumeData(this.state.data)); // using `data` would work as well...
}
```

Comment: Is this considered safe, good practice, or may it cause unseen side effects?

Comment: It's safe, AFAIK. But it may not be the best practice since app level state is recommended (with redux). Thus, you probably could avoid passing `consumeData` as a prop from parent.

Comment: What if setState is being invoked through a props function from a child component? How can you force setState to execute before executing the next line in the child component?

Comment: If somebody is wondering about a parameter for callback function, there is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764920/pass-parameter-from-a-function-to-this-setstate-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding access to the state that just changed, @Samuli Hakoniemi's answer is the preferred way in the docs (iirc).

I'd say the following code should also run the state change before the data handling:

```
handleSomeEvent(data) {
    const _handleDataChange = async () => {
    this.props.consumeData(this.state.data) 
    }

    this.setState({data: data})
    _handleDataChange();
}
```

As _handleDataChange is an async call, it should be run after the (async) setState call.