# Pass parameter from a function to this.setState callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a facing a bit of a problem here. I'm trying to pass a parameter from  a function to `this.setState` callback, but I can't figure out how is this possible.

My code looks like this:

```
selectHandler(event){
    this.setState({
        selectedImage: event.target
    }, (event) => {
        this.markSelectedHandler(event)
    })
}

markSelectedHandler(e){
    e.target.classList.add('active')
    if(e.target !== this.state.selectedImage && this.state.selectedImage){
        this.state.selectedImage.classList.remove('active')
        e.target.classList.add('active')
    }
}
```

e.target returns null, any idea why this happens ?

Comment: The `event` will not work async. You will need to extract the values or use `e.persist()` https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: Also to be honest, you should not add your class with DOM manipulating but instead add it in your render `<img className={this.state.selectedImage === myImage ?  'active' : undefined} />`

Comment: Well, I've learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: Often you will _never_ need to work directly with the DOM elements in React.

Comment: Feel free to add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event will not work async. You will need to extract the values or use e.persist() reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

You could however say:

```
selectHandler(event){
    const { target } = event;

    this.setState({
        selectedImage: target
    }, () => {
        this.markSelectedHandler(target)
    })
}

markSelectedHandler(target){
    target.classList.add('active')
    if(target!== this.state.selectedImage && this.state.selectedImage){
        this.state.selectedImage.classList.remove('active')
        target.classList.add('active')
    }
}
```

But I will recommend against it..

To be honest, you should not add your class with DOM manipulating but instead add it in your render `<img className={this.state.selectedImage === myImage ? 'active' : undefined} />`

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing your `event` in this code:

```
selectHandler(event){
    this.setState({
        selectedImage: event.target
    }, (event) => {
        this.markSelectedHandler(event)
    })
}
```

You need not to shadow, by not passing a parameter with the same name (`event` to the `setState` callback):

```
selectHandler(event){
    this.setState({
        selectedImage: event.target
    }, () => {
        this.markSelectedHandler(event)
    })
}
```

Comment: Already did that, still not working. probably I should add / remove class after rendering the component

Answer (score 0):

Try not sending `event` as an argument to the callback

eg you have written

```
selectHandler(event){
    this.setState({
        selectedImage: event.target
    }, (event) => {
        this.markSelectedHandler(event)
    })
}
```

Write like this instead

```
selectHandler(event){
    this.setState({
        selectedImage: event.target
    }, () => {
        this.markSelectedHandler(event)
    })
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer below.

Comment: yes I realized it now. It's coming null only. That answer is correct.